# Visible ActionBar with opened NavDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, materialdrawer

Is it possible to keep the actionbar visible using the mikepenz's [material drawer library](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer)?

[image: Visible ActionBar with opened NavDrawer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Just see the sample application. This contains the `CustomContainerActivity` which showcases how you can have a `Drawer` which is below the `Toolbar`

```
public class CustomContainerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //save our header or result
    private Drawer result = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample_custom_container_dark_toolbar);

        // Handle Toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_item_custom_container_drawer);

        //Create the drawer
        result = new DrawerBuilder(this)
                //this layout have to contain child layouts
                .withRootView(R.id.drawer_container)
                .withToolbar(toolbar)
                .withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .addDrawerItems(
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_free_play).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_gamepad),
                        new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_custom).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_eye),
                        new SectionDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_section_header),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_cog),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_help).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_question).withEnabled(false),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_open_source).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_github),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.drawer_item_contact).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bullhorn)
                )
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //add the values which need to be saved from the drawer to the bundle
        outState = result.saveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        //handle the back press :D close the drawer first and if the drawer is closed close the activity
        if (result != null && result.isDrawerOpen()) {
            result.closeDrawer();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

Also note the different xml layout which is used in this `Activity`.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:elevation="4dp" />

    <!-- the layout which will contain (host) the drawerLayout -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- the layout which will be the content of the activity (which will be hosted inside the drawer (NOT the list of the drawer)) -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtLabel"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This will produce the following:

[image: CustomContainerActivity MaterialDrawer]

Comment: It is working. I will accept the answer as soon as it is possible. You were so quick, thank you!